# Mouse click puts garbage input to a GDB server terminal session

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, gdb

When the GDB `--gdbtui` is running in my terminal (Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS) and I click somewhere on the terminal window, or scroll with a mouse wheel, random characters are printed into the command line. It can be pretty annoying.

I don't have this issue for a terminal session without the GDB running, so I am suspicious about the GDB itself.

I tried different mouses, laptop touch-pad, but it's still the same.

Answer (score 0):

What version of GDB are you using?  I suspect this issue may be fixed by [this](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=commit;h=82a5082ed3f00b8d7bd1e3810c6eeb4351e35286) commit, which is included in GDB 11 and later releases.